# The XKivy Github package : Brief Overview

Tags: python, kivy, python-module, kivymd, python-for-android

I'm trying to use the xkivy Python module to do change `XScrollBoxLayout` padding using the _container. I'm having trouble with changing it ,it says "XScrollBoxLayout object has no attribute '_container' " Can anyone help?

I installed it on pypi using
`pip install xkivy`

```
import kivy
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from xkivy.uix.scrollview import XScrollBoxLayout
from xkivy.uix.layouts import XBoxLayout
from xkivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp

class Main(XBoxLayout):
   xradius = ListProperty([10]*4)
   xbg_color = ListProperty([1,0,0,1])

   def add_widgets(self):
      self.scroll_layout = XScrollBoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
      self.add_widget(self.sroll_layout)

   def on_parent(self ,*args):
      self.add_widgets()

class MainApp(MDApp):
   def build(self):
      return Main()

MainApp().run()
```

I tried changing the padding by changing `XScrollBoxLayout.padding` but no change so im trying to use the container of XScrollBoxLayout ,that is XBoxLayout.